# Copying/Pasting Multiple Pictures with VBA (Excel to Outlook)

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm trying to export multiple screenshots from Excel to Outlook but am having trouble reactivating the Outlook window for the 2nd screenshot.  What can I do after copying `picRng1` and pasting it, to reactivate the Outlook window to paste `picRng2` with a break inbetween ?  Can I use `.HTMLBody = ""<br>"` to separate the 2 pictures ?

```
picRng1.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
picRng2.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture


With Email


    wdDoc.Range.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdChartPicture


     With wdDoc
          .InlineShapes(1).Height = 700
     End With

    .Subject = "Daily Ops Report"
    .To = sTo
    .Display

End With
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work using paragraphs:

```
        picRng2.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture



    With Email

        With wdDoc.Paragraphs(4)
            .Range.InsertParagraphAfter
            .Range.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdChartPicture
            .Range.ParagraphFormat.LineSpacingRule = wdLineSpaceDouble
            With wdDoc
                .InlineShapes(1).Height = 700
            End With
         End With

         '.Body = "Hello"

        .Subject = "Daily Ops Report"
        .To = sTo
        .Display

    End With

    picRng1.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture

    With Email
            With wdDoc.Paragraphs(2)
            .Range.InsertParagraphAfter
            .Range.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdChartPicture
            .Range.ParagraphFormat.LineSpacingRule = wdLineSpaceDouble
            With wdDoc
                .InlineShapes(1).Height = 700
            End With
         End With

    End With

    With Email
            With wdDoc.Paragraphs(1)
            .Range.InsertParagraphAfter
            .Range.ParagraphFormat.LineSpacingRule = wdLineSpaceDouble
         End With

    End With

 End Sub
```