# Pasting multiple screenshots to single Outlook email

Tags: vba, for-loop, outlook, screenshot, paste

I am trying to paste screenshots of tables from a number of intranet sites to an email.

Each screenshot is pasted into a new message, whereas I need them all in the same message.

How do I focus on the initial email to paste all screen shots when looping through all the urls?

I referred to [Copying/Pasting Multiple Pictures with VBA (Excel to Outlook)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57598998/copying-pasting-multiple-pictures-with-vba-excel-to-outlook).

Here is my code:

```vb
Sub test()
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim ob_urls(1 To 2) As String
Dim item As Variant

'urls
my_urls(1) = "work intranet url 1 - removed"
my_urls(2) = "work intranet url 2 - removed"

Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium
ie.Visible = True

'loop through urls
For Each item In my_urls

    ie.navigate item
    'make page wide enough to see tables.
    ie.Width = 1400
    ie.Visible = True
    
    Do
        If ie.readyState = 4 Then
            Exit Do
        Else
            DoEvents
        End If
    Loop
    
    
    'delay to load before screen shot, javascript loading
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:7"))
    
    'Print Screen
    Application.SendKeys "(%{1068})" '
    DoEvents
    
    'Prepare the email
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    OutApp.Session.Logon
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    
    On Error Resume Next
    
    With OutMail
        .To = "someone@org.com"
        .Subject = "test"
        .display
        .GetInspector.Activate
            
        'Get its Word editor
         OutMail.display
         Dim wordDoc As Word.document
         Set wordDoc = OutMail.GetInspector.WordEditor
          
         Application.SendKeys "(^v)"
            
         ' Crop Image
         For Each shp In wordDoc.InlineShapes
             shp.PictureFormat.CropTop = 200
             shp.PictureFormat.CropBottom = 200
         Next
     End With
     On Error GoTo 0
            
     'toggle true/false to refocus
     ie.Visible = False
Next item
End Sub
```

Comment: Move the lines from `Set OutApp =...` to `Set OutMail =...` to before `'loop through urls`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this one out.

Instead of:

```
    'Prepare the email
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    OutApp.Session.Logon
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
```

Doing this gets the screenshots all on one email:

```
    If OutApp Is Nothing Then Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    OutApp.Session.Logon
    If OutMail Is Nothing Then Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
```

Peace.